# Mongoose query on NodeJS server returns NULL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm querying Twitter for locations, which is successfully returned. These locations are then stored in a mongodb. When I query the database via command line for the location: 'United Kingdom', the location data is returned. However when I query the database on the NodeJS server, nothing is returned (null).

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/environment');

var Location = require('./api/twitter/location/twitter/location.model');

// Connect to database
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
    process.exit(-1);
});

// Populate DB with sample data
if(config.seedDB) { 
    Location.remove({}, function(err) { 
       console.log('Location collection removed');
    });
}

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
  serveClient: config.env !== 'production',
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});

require('./config/socketio')(socketio);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Start server
server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;

// Query Twitter for locations
getLocations();

// Find location 'United Kingdom'
var woeId = Location.findOne({'name': 'United Kingdom'}, 'woeId', function (err, location) {
    console.log(location);
    if (!err) {
        return location;
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// Gather available locations from Twitter
function getLocations() {
    twitterClient.get('trends/available', {}, function(errors, locations, response) {
        if (!errors) {
             storeLocations(locations);
        } else {
            console.log(errors);
        }
    });
}

// Store locations in database
function storeLocations(locations) {

    for (var location in locations) {

        Location.create({
            name: locations[location].name,
            placeType: {
                code: locations[location].placeType.code,
                name: locations[location].placeType.name
            },
            parentId: locations[location].parentid,
            country: locations[location].country,
            woeId: locations[location].woeid,
            countryCode: locations[location].countryCode
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js your call to findOne is asynchronous.

```
// Find location 'United Kingdom'
var woeId = Location.findOne({'name': 'United Kingdom'}, 'woeId', function (err, location) {
    console.log(location);
    if (!err) {
        return location;
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

It looks like you expect the return value (location) that you provide from the callback to be propogated out to var woeId, but that will never happen.

Instead you need to perform whatever action is needed from within the callback, which could be as simple as setting a global variable, but depends on how you plan on using it.  For example:

```
// Find location 'United Kingdom'
var woeId;
Location.findOne({'name': 'United Kingdom'}, 'woeId', function (err, location) {
        console.log(location);
        if (!err) {
                woeId = location;
        } else {
                console.log(err);
        }
});
```

But just remember that the value won't be available until the asynchronous callback is invoked.